# Increase height of tableCell dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I searched for the increase height of table cell. I got few answer. Those are not appropriate for the my condition.

**Case:**

I have table cell with height default 150. Content added on table cell (Titile,Image,action) are view in table cell.we load Image through **"UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"**. We have images of different height.

How to increase/decrease cell height after image load in the cell?

Comment: Please attached the table screenshots..

Comment: it is very hard to tell you the solution, because the key of the "problem" is still missing: *when* do you get the image (and its size) for the current cell?

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to reload your particular cell

```
// Build the index path
NSIndexPath* indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:2];
// Add them in an index path array
NSArray* indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath1, nil];
// Launch reload for the two index path
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

And have to return the height of cell from `tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath:` then it will call your `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

P.S. I'm assuming that you are doing lazy loading (loading images after the cell is created)

Answer (score 0):

After image loading in tableview `cellForRowAtIndexPath` calculate the height of the loaded image. Give the rowheight in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Try This Code

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 UIImage *Image= [imageAry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%f",Image.frame.size.height);
    return size.height + 10;
}
```

Comment: UIImage have not a property like frame and its height so it will give the error..

Answer (score 0):

just set the height of cell using `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method like bellow...

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    UIImage *Tempimage= [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView *imgTemp = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:Tempimage];
    return imgTemp.frame.size.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not use the `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h` but the idea for calculating the height of row is to calculate the height of image after loaded some where

hope this method help you

```
- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest 
              placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage 
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error))failure;
```

and after image loaded in `success` calculate the image height `image.size.height` and add this in array for table

```
NSMutableDictionary *record = [array objectAtIndex:index];
[record setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",image.size.height] forKey:@"imageheight"];
[array  replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:record];
[tableView reloadData];
```

and set the height of row like this

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    NSMutableDictionary *record = [array objectAtIndex:index];
    if ( [record objectForkey:@"imageheight"] ) {
        return [[record objectForkey:@"imageheight"] floatValue] + yourmargin);
        // yourmargin may be 150 or what ever be
    } else {
        return 150;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u for answer. Is it possible without calculating image height? once image get download adjust the height of the cell. As from your answer we have every thing in our hand then we calculate height.

Comment: Even i try download image using  "setImageWithURLRequest" but images not get download. Meanwhile control goes 'success' block after the  datasource function "heightForRowAtIndexPath" get executed. There for I do not get image height.

Comment: you have to `[tableView reloadData];` in `success` method till success is not called height is 150

Answer (score 0):

After downloading image write following lines:

[self.tblStoryCardView beginUpdates];
[self.tblStoryCardView endUpdates];

And downloaded image height in row height method.

I uploaded a dummy project in github. you can check it:
https://github.com/govindprasadguptacool/Dynamic-Table-Cell-Height

Comment: Please post your code in your answer. Links may become invalid over time.

Comment: This is my github library link and it is working fine